# How can I color specific rows in my listview?

Tags: java, android, listview

How I can color any specific rows?

I have tried using the `getView` method, but didn't succeed. I don't want to color any row based on a condition, I just want to hardcode rows with specific colors.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    listview= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);


    mylist.add("random1");
    mylist.add("random2");
    mylist.add("random3");
    mylist.add("random4");


    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mylist);

    listview.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                  int position, long id) {
        String position2 =String.valueOf(position);

            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,minutes.class);

            i.putExtra("position",position2 );
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

}
```

My XML looks like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false">

</ListView>
```

Comment: you need to override getView on a custom adapter and set the color there

Answer (score 0):

my recomendation is that if you are going to hardcode the colors, create your own adapter and hardcode them in the getview method.

other option is to cicle trough the childs from the listview, with

```
for(int i = 0; listview.getchildcount() > i; i++){
   View child = listview.getChildAt(i);
   //Your code...
}
```

but thats not very recomendable, since childs change on scrolling the listview...